# Inspect/disable bytecode check & regeneration in Python 2

Tags: python, performance, python-import, python-internals

I would like to force Python to use pre-compiled bytecode files that I provide, and avoid any other behavior that 'runs the script' but wastes time trying to regenerate the bytecode.  Python however is designed to make this behavior generally transparent to the user, so I can't find any obvious ways to control (or even inspect) what it's doing in this regard.

**My question(s):**

1. Is my only option to remove the .py source, leaving only .pyc files?  (I don't want to do that because keeping the source around has proven very useful for debugging in this scenario.)
2. How can I check up on this behavior to see what's really happening?

### Background & Motivation

I am creating a package of Python modules to be distributed over read-only network file system, and I include pre-compiled bytecode as .pyc along with the Python packages.  I can guarantee that the end users will always be using it with the same version of Python, on the same Linux OS, with the same kernel, in the same environment, etc, and **therefore should never have to regenerate the bytecode**.  (This is a special setup for a mid-sized scientific experiment where we enforce these things in the environment we provide for our software developers.  The package manager in this environment *refuses* to set up packages that don't match each other in the ways we specify.)

In this context, I want to ensure that Python does not try to regenerate bytecode or write .pyc's because we want to avoid slow startup times importing some large modules (matplotlib, scipy, and some others).  Python's default behavior, as I understand it, is to

1. *always* check if the .pyc files are stale
2. *always* regenerate this bytecode if it is stale
3. *always* try to overwrite the .pyc file with the new bytecode, and
4. *never* tell the user if overwriting the .pyc failed.

Step 1 should not be necessary, but I'm not too worried about it because it only requires checking a few bytes.  I think it doesn't take much time (even on our network file system, which is optimized for serving up small or partial binary files).  I suppose I could be wrong about this for packages that have many .pyc files?

Step 2 should never be necessary after the package is built.  If this happens then there is a bug in the package management.

Step 3 will always fail here because this is a read-only filesystem.  If this happens then we need to know about it.

Step 4 is frustrating because I can't tell what's going on.  And I have seen modules (e.g. matplotlib) which load more quickly on subsequent imports in this scenario, which I don't understand.

Comment: For completeness, I have found something that *looks like* it tells me whether a module's bytecode came from a .pyc file, or if it was generated from .py at runtime and just held in memory.  Given an object, `inspect.getmodule()` prints the module and its filename.  By experimenting with directory write permissions and/or python version I can get it to show the filename with '\*.py' or '\*.pyc', but I am not sure if this really tells me what I want.  (And `str(inspect.getmodule(xyz.fn)).split("'")[-2].endswith('.pyc')` is severely goofy.)